# Unable to configure MySQL during reinstallation

Tags: mysql, devops

The MySQL service I have on my **Windows 10** computer suddenly stopped and refused to start again. I tried many different options to fix it and they all didn't work, so I decided to uninstall MySQL and reinstall it.

I deleted these folders before uninstall:

- C:\Program Files\MySQL\
- C:\ProgramData\MySQL\
- C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\

During re-installing, I noticed that Connector .NET failed to install.

I am not sure if that was why the problem occurred, but the installer has repeatedly failed the "Backing up MySQL Database" step of configuration. Every time I run it, it displays this error message:

```
Starting MySQL Server in order to run the mysql_upgrade tool.
Warning: There may be some errors thrown by MySQL Server, the mysql_upgrade tool is going to be run next to attempt to fix database incompatibilities.
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.21...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --port=3306 --datadir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data" --console...
Process for mysqld, with ID 12424, has been started successfully and is running.
Successfully started process for MySQL Server 8.0.21.
2020-08-19T16:52:16.133223Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 7612
2020-08-19T16:52:16.251679Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2020-08-19T16:52:16.254844Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-08-19T16:52:16.255289Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-08-19T16:52:16.261307Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.........................
Running mysqldump tool to backup the database...
Backup files will be dumped to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Backup\mysql_dump-2020-08-19T12.55.23.sql".

Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=root --default-auth=caching_sha2_password --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --routines --events --single-transaction=TRUE --all-databases --result-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Backup\mysql_dump-2020-08-19T12.55.23.sql"...
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect
Process for mysqldump, with ID 18972, was run successfully and exited with code 2.
Ended configuration step: Backing up MySQL database


Found existing data directory, no need to initialize the database.
```

I can't skip the configuration as MySQL still hasn't appeared as a service.

I tried manually creating a data folder in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\ but that still hasn't solved the problem. Can anyone give me an idea of why I am receiving this error?

Comment: I would have been tempted to Uninstall and then see what needed cleaning up! Anyway this line pretty much say it all `Failed to find valid data directory.` So your install appears to have not completed all the steps, probably because the uninstall got a little confused by all the missing folders

Comment: This may be relevant/helpful; https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/8ptllm/how_do_i_start_the_mysql_server_in_windows_please/

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/62003723/2004860

Comment: Might also be worth checking that the old MySQL service got properly cleaned out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly how I solved this, but I do remember looking this question up online and I found out that there still might be a registry value that thinks Connector .NET exists (even though it doesn't), which is why the program keeps failing to upload.

I installed CCleaner, which cleaned up these rogue registry values, and then I was able to get MySQL to work. Hope this helps anyone else who is in the same position as me.